# The root directory and slash in cd command

Tags: linux, command-line, cd-command

I'm new to Linux and I want to understand this simple Linux command:

```
cd /boot/../dev
```

- `cd` = change directory
- The first `/` = go to the root directory
- `boot` = is the name of a directory
- The second `/` = ..... ?  he can't mean go to the root directory
  because after that we have `..` which means go to  the parent directory
  of the actual directory and root doesn't have one
- `..` = means go the parent directory
- `dev` = is the name of a directory

Comment: The slash only means "root directory" when at the beginning of a path; otherwise is just a path separator.

Comment: Also, while not demonstrated by your example, the parent of the root directory is the root directory itself: `/..` or `/../../..` are legal and mean the same as `/`.

Answer (score 2):

The command does the following:

go to `/boot`

```
cd /boot
```

go to parent directory in this case `/`:

```
..
```

go to `/dev`

```
/dev
```

which is the same as

```
cd /dev
```

Try the following:

```
cd /boot # you are in /boot
cd ..    # you go to parent dir /
cd /dev  # you change to /dev
```

---

There are `relative` paths and `absolute` paths:

**Relative paths** are those that depend in which place I'm actually, they    don't have a `/` in front. Example:

I'm in `/home/user`

```
cd Downloads # As you can see, there's no / in front
```

takes me to `/home/user/Downloads`, which is the full path.

**Absoulute paths** are those that describe the full path from the root, wich is the first slash `/`.

I'm in `/home/user`

```
cd /usr/bin # there's a / in front
```

takes me to `/usr/bin`.

Every time you put a `/` in front, you are making a full path, it's like you are telling to the system "from root, go to..."

---

So this won't work

I am in `/home/user` and I want to go to `/usr/bin`

```
cd usr/bin
```

will throw:

```
bash: cd: usr/bin: No such file or directory
```

because there's no `/home/user/usr/bin`

And if I am in `/home/user` and want to go `/home/user/Downlods`, this won't work:

```
cd /Downloads
```

beacause the system will look up for the directory `root/Downloads`, not `/home/user/Downloads`

Comment: it's necessary to put a slash before the directory name ?

Comment: Yes, the leading slash means "absolute" path, vs. a "relative" path, which is "from here." So if you were already in `/etc/` and wanted to get to `/etc/init.d/` you do `cd init.d` with _no_ slash.

Comment: @OussamaBousalem I edited the answer, I hope is clear enough.

Comment: Yep it's thank you